# Cable management ideas?

Tags: cable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to declutter and organize the cables on and under my desk?](https://superuser.com/questions/8483/how-to-declutter-and-organize-the-cables-on-and-under-my-desk)

Anyone have any good ideas on how to manage cables?

Answer (score 7):

Browse the `cablemanagement` tag at [Lifehacker.com](http://lifehacker.com):

> http://lifehacker.com/t/cablemanagement/

Some top ideas/articles:

- [Top 10 Ways to Get Cables Under Control.](http://lifehacker.com/364054/top-10-ways-to-get-cables-under-control)
- [Use an old coiled phone cord.](http://lifehacker.com/5646277/manage-cables-with-an-old-coiled-phone-cord)
- [Use a binder clip.](http://lifehacker.com/5638954/our-favorite-office-objects-the-endlessly-versatile-binder-clip)
- [Use binder clips as cable catchers redux](http://lifehacker.com/5499838/binder-clips-as-cable-catchers-redux).
- [Repurpose a Hanger to Tidy Long Cables](http://lifehacker.com/5536059/repurpose-a-hanger-to-tidy-long-cables)

Answer (score 3):

Many office supply stores sell velcro ties to bundle them together. I recommend against the plastic zip ties, as you need to have a scissors on hand every time you want to (dis)connect a cable.

Example of the VElcro ones: http://cableorganizer.com/wire-wrap/