# Straightening keyboard/mouse/monitor cables

Tags: cable

I recently switched back to a wired keyboard and mouse for my desktop machine because I was tired of chewing through batteries.
The keyboard cable is somewhat kinked from how the wire was wrapped in storage, and I'd like it to be nice and straight.

I've tried to unbend each of the kinks, but either I'm not good at it or it's not working.
I found a link [suggesting that boiling water](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2011/04/remove-kinks-in-cables-with-a-glass-of-hot-water-and-tape/) may be a fix for some finer-gauged cables, but the keyboard cable is more substantial than earbud wires, so I don't expect it to work.  I think the problem is in the metal, not the plastic.
I'm aware of the cable-hiding and management products mentioned in [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/8483/how-to-declutter-and-organize-the-cables-on-and-under-my-desk), but I don't want to hide mine, just straighten them.

Is there a good way to straighten a cable that will get rid of kinks?

Answer (score 1):

Cable sleeves tend to be PVC and plastic means non-elastic.
What you want are some elastic properties, which you can get with heat and tension. The copper must be gently kinked in the opposite direction. Dont over do it.